# What is the correct way to format a module controller action URL?

Tags: modules

Consider the following Craft 3 example module structure:

```
modules/
    businesslogic/
        controllers/ExampleController.php
        BusinessLogic.php
```

...and consider the following action in ExampleController.php:

```
public function actionExampleRoute()
{
    die('in example-route action');
}
```

Assuming everything is set up and configured correctly, is this the correct URL for triggering the action in ExampleController.php?

```
http://my-craft-site/business-logic/example/example-route
```

If so, this is not working for me; it instead results in a 404/Template not found error. I'm not sure if I misunderstand how to determine the correct URL or if I set up something incorrectly.

I am working with the example provided [here](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-businesslogic) and I believe I have followed the [instructions](https://doublesecretagency.github.io/craft-businesslogic/installation) correctly. The instructions include a simple test of the module, and the test succeeds--I'm just not able to get the controller action to work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of the issue turned out to be an incorrect controllerNamespace reference in the [Business Logic Template](https://github.com/doublesecretagency/craft-businesslogic) example. If anyone else is using the example project to jumpstart a Craft module, be aware of the following:

In that example, the ExampleController.php controller specifies this namespace...

```
namespace modules\businesslogic\controllers;
```

...but BusinessLogic.php sets the controllerNameSpace like this, (note that it's missing **modules\**)...

```
// Adjust controller namespace for console requests
if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest()) {
    $this->controllerNamespace = 'businesslogic\\console\\controllers';
}
```

...it worked for me after I changed it to match the ExampleController namespace, (note the addition of **modules\** as well as handling both console and web requests)...

```
// Adjust controller namespace for console requests
if (Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsConsoleRequest()) {
    $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\businesslogic\\console\\controllers';
} else {
    $this->controllerNamespace = 'modules\\businesslogic\\controllers';
}
```

**EDIT**

To answer my own original question, the correct way to call the module action is:

```
http://my-craft-site/actions/businesslogic/example/example-route
```

Note that **/actions** precedes the *module/controller/action* portion of the URL, and that the controller and action are [kebab-cased](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/kebab_case). As @nstCactus points out, the module is the module handle defined in *config/app.php*.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the module handle you chose in *config/app.php* (the module handle is the key affected to your module in the `modules` array).

If you want the URL to be `/business-logic/example/example-route`, the module key must be `business-logic`:

```php
use modules\businesslogic\BusinessLogic;

return [
    'modules' => [
        'business-logic' => BusinessLogic::class,
    ],
    'bootstrap' => [
        'business-logic',
    ]
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I'm using controllers for direct URL access (e.g. from JavaScript via an XHR or fetch request), I've accessed them using a query string rather than relying on rewritten URLs. So, like this:

```
https://my-craft-site/index.php?p=actions/business-logic/example/example-route
```

If the controller method is intended to be triggered from a form submit, you can just use the `actionInput` Twig function:

```
<form method="post">
   {{ actionInput('business-logic/example/example-route') }}

   {# Some form input fields here... #}

    <button type="submit">
</form>
```